# php removing a duplicate in a string

Tags: php, duplicates

First of all thanks to Dave Chen for helping me with the merger.

Now I ran into a problem. When I merge using this code:

```
$string1 = "
;1
2
3
;4
";

$string2 = "
;1
;2
;3
;4
;5
;6
";

echo implode("\r\n",array_unique(array_merge(explode("\r\n",$string1),explode("\r\n",$string2))));
```

The output is **;1 2 3 ;4 ;2 ;3 ;5 ;6** but I need it to be **;1 2 3 ;4 ;5 ;6**

Comment: Must you have the column `;` sign  ? From my point of view `;2 != 2`

Comment: what do the semicolons represent?

Comment: explain `"3" == ";3"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
echo implode(" ", crazyMerge($string1, $string2));
```

Output

```
 ;1 2 3 ;4 ;5 ;6
```

Function Used

```
function crazyMerge($a, $b) {
    // Some Cleanup
    $a = array_map("trim", explode("\r\n", $a));
    $b = array_map("trim", explode("\r\n", $b));

    $ab = array();
    foreach($a as $v) {
        if (! in_array(ltrim($v, ";"), $ab) && ! in_array($v, $ab))
            $ab[] = $v;
    }
    foreach($b as $k => $v) {
        if (! in_array(ltrim($v, ";"), $ab) && ! in_array($v, $ab))
            $ab[] = $v;
    }
    return $ab;
}
```